# Combine multiple queries into single muti row output

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a FETCH query that is output the correct information but it is outputting each loop through the fetch as a separate query for output.

What I'm looking to do is output the results into a single table (or in my case I will end up creating a view with this query)

```
DECLARE @THID Cursor
DECLARE @THIDValue int

SET @THID = CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT       
        Transheader.ID
    FROM            
        TransHeader WITH (nolock) 
    INNER JOIN
        TransHeaderUserField WITH (nolock) ON TransHeader.ID = TransHeaderUserField.ID
    WHERE        
        (TransHeaderUserField.Rework = '1') 
        AND TransHeader.ID IS NOT NULL

OPEN @THID

FETCH NEXT FROM @THID INTO @THIDValue

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT        
        (SELECT 
             SUM(totPartCost) 
         FROM
             TransDetail 
         WHERE
             TransHeaderID = @THIDValue) AS ThePartCost,  
        TransHeader.OrderNumber, TransHeader.ClassTypeID, 
        TransHeader.OrderCreatedDate, TransHeaderUserField.Rework, 
        TransHeaderUserField.Rework_Type, 
        TransHeaderUserField.Rework_Orders, TransHeaderUserField.Rework_Employee, 
        TransHeaderUserField.Rework_Department, TransHeader.Description
    FROM            
        TransHeader WITH (nolock) 
    INNER JOIN
        TransHeaderUserField WITH (nolock) ON TransHeader.ID = TransHeaderUserField.ID
    WHERE        
        (TransHeaderUserField.Rework = '1') AND TransHeader.ID = @THIDValue
    ORDER BY 
        TransHeaderUserField.Rework_Department, TransHeaderUserField.Rework_Employee

    FETCH NEXT FROM @THID INTO @THIDValue
END

CLOSE @THID
DEALLOCATE @THID
```

[image]

Comment: Set [Bad Habits to kick - putting NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) - it is not recommended (at all) to use this everywhere - quite the contrary!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INSERT each SELECT into a temporary table, and after all the iterations of the loop are done, SELECT * from the temporary table.